# Unload Event for a Struts Action

Tags: session, struts

We've got this "back" link on our page. Go to the "previous" page.

There are several links on this page that simply reload the page with different parameters. To make sure the back link is always accurate, we save the original referring page in a session variable and then use this session variable to "Create" the referring link.

One problem exists here:

How do we clear the session variable when the back link is clicked. The back link is formed through using a JSP page. What would be ideal is to have a "unLoad" event we could override in struts but I haven't had any luck finding such a thing.

Any suggestions? :D